# A series of Manipulate activities in a notebook

Tags: manipulate

I have a series of Manipulate activities in a single notebook I am preparing for a presentation tomorrow. After the fourth one moves so that it is partially in view, I get the blinking black cell. I tried `TrackedSymbols:>{k}` but that did not work. Any thoughts? The sequence of Manipulates follows. They are all in separate input cells.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[x - k], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}],
 {{k, 0}, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi], Appearance -> "Labeled"}]

Manipulate[
 Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x - k]}, {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}],
 {{k, 0}, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi], Appearance -> "Labeled"}]

Manipulate[
 Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x - k]}, {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]},
  GridLines -> Automatic],
 {{k, 0}, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi], Appearance -> "Labeled"}]

Manipulate[
 label = TraditionalForm[x - k];
 Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x - k]}, {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]},
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  PlotLabel -> 
   Pane[StringForm["y = f(``)", label], 200, Alignment -> Center]
  ],
 {{k, 0}, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi], Appearance -> "Labeled"}]

Manipulate[
 label = TraditionalForm[x - k];
 Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x - k]}, {x, -6, 6},
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  PlotLabel -> 
   Pane[StringForm["y = f(``)", label], 200, Alignment -> Center]
  ],
 {{k, 0}, -6, 6, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]

Manipulate[
 label = TraditionalForm[x - k];
 Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x - k]}, {x, -6, 6},
  GridLines -> {Range[-6, 6, 1], Automatic},
  PlotLabel -> 
   Pane[StringForm["y = f(``)", label], 200, Alignment -> Center]
  ],
 {{k, 0}, -6, 6, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keep all your symbols localised to the `Manipulate` by adding `{x, None}, {label, None}` at the end. Example:

```
Manipulate[label = TraditionalForm[x - k];
 Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x - k]}, {x, -6, 6}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Pane[StringForm["y = f(``)", label], 200, 
    Alignment -> Center]], {{k, 0}, -6, 6, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {x, None}, {label, None}]
```

This way each `Manipulate` is entirely self contained rather than having global variables shared across each `Manipulate`

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Mike Honeychurch advised one further reason for problems may be that many dynamic object working at once may be too difficult for your computer. Only those `Manipulate`s are active that are actually on the screen. However, these also may be too much in some cases. I always try to have different `Manipulate`statements on different pages of my presentation, if possible.